# How to upload base64 encoded pdf directly to s3 with nodejs/aws-sdk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm attempting to upload a base64 encoded pdf to S3 with the following code without having to write the file to the filesystem.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.putBase64 = async (object_name, buffer, bucket) => {
const params = {
    Key: object_name,
    Body: buffer,
    Bucket: bucket,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: 'application/pdf'
};
const response = await S3.upload(params).promise();
return response;
};
```

Where buffer is a blank pdf encoded to base64. When attempting to open the file on s3, I get "We can't open this file
Something went wrong." upon attempting to open it.

However, if I write the base64 encoding into a file and THEN upload it, it works.

```
await fs.writeFileSync(`./somepdf.pdf`, base_64, 'base64');
exports.put = async (object_name, file_location, bucket, content_type) => {
const file_content = fs.readFileSync(file_location);
const params = {
    Key: object_name,
    Body: './somepdf.pdf',
    Bucket: bucket,
    ContentType: 'application/pdf'
};
const response = await S3.upload(params).promise();
return response;
};
```

I notice that when uploading the file directly, the file encoding when viewing the file through a text editor it isn't base64 encoded, but viewing the file uploaded as strictly defined contentencoding base64 shows the base64. I attempted to convert the base64 to a blob using atob but that yielded the same results, so I assume there's a parameter I maybe missing or a header.

Comment: Why would you base64-encode it!?

Comment: @Brad I have a single POST request that has the pdf data and other metadata I need. I'm using docusign as a reference as they encode their PDFs in base64 when they upload to their servers via their POST. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/documents

What other alternative should I consider?

Comment: Base64 encoding adds 33% overhead to the storage and bandwidth requirements, as well as essentially a waste of CPU and memory.  There are very few actual good use cases for it.  This DocuSign API doesn't seem to be very well designed.  In your case, I'd recommend either accepting a multipart POST, or make two HTTP requests.  It isn't entirely clear to me what you're doing, but it sounds like an even better way would be to sign the PUT URL, send that back to the client in your API response, and let it upload directly rather than going through your API server.

Comment: Also, if you ever absolutely have to include binary resources together in one ball, I'd recommend using something like CBOR.  It's standardized, supports binary, more types than JSON, is extensible, streamable, works client-side as well as server-side, and doesn't have a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it by making this change:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.putBase64 = async (object_name, buffer, bucket) => {

    const params = {
        Key: object_name,
        Body: Buffer.from(buffer, 'base64'), // <---------
        Bucket: bucket,
        ContentType: 'application/pdf'
    };

    return await S3.upload(params).promise();
};
```

Comment: This looks like the better solution, it takes care of the offset for you.

Comment: This was the only answer to work for me, after trying solutions that suggest using `s3.putObject` instead of `s3.upload`

Answer (score 3):

Create a new buffer

```
const newBuffer = buffer.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, "")
```

Now use this new buffer in params. This should work!

Comment: For those having issues with base64 uploads of file types docx, xlsx, etc. This is the answer. thank you!