# How to upload modified PDF file to AWS s3 from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3

I've a requirement to

1. Download a PDF file from AWS S3 storage. (Key1)
2. Do some modifications.
3. Upload the modified PDF file back to S3 storage. (Key2)
   The Uploaded file is a new file (K2). Not overwriting the existing file (K1)

Library used for modifying PDFs : [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/)
All the executions like downloading/modification/uploading of PDF are being done in AWS Lambda. The runtime is node.js 14.x
The objects in S3 bucket can be accessed through CDN as public access is blocked.

I'm able to download the file, then do the modifications and upload to S3. But when I open the file using CDN URL for the object, it is showing encoded text (garbage). Not the PDF preview of the file.

Downloading PDF file from S3.

```
const params = {
    Bucket: bucket_name,
    Key: key
};

// GET FILE AND RETURN PROMISE.
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
        try {

            const obj = data.Body;        // <<-- getting Uint8Array
            resolve(obj);
        } catch (e) {
            reject(err);
        } 
    });
});
```

Doing Modification on PDF file

```
async modificationFunction(opts) => {
    const { fileData } = opts;        //<<---- Unit8Array data from above snippet.
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(fileData);

// Do Some Modification like drawing lines.

    const modifiedPDFData = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64({ dataUri: true });
    return modifiedPDFData;           //<<--- Base64 data of modifications.
}
```

Uploading PDF file

```
const params = {
    Bucket: bucket_name,
    Key: key,
    Body: data,             //<<--- Base64 data of modification from above snippet
};

try {
  await s3.upload(params).promise();
  console.log('File uploaded:', `s3://${bucket_name}/${key}`);
}
```

Content of the PDF when viewed using CDN URL is attached. It is encoded/garbage content.

Same PDF when downloaded to laptop from AWS S3 using manual download from S3 bucket is showing the contents properly like a normal PDF file.

Referenced many online resources/stackoverflow threads:

1. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62746856/how-to-upload-base64-encoded-pdf-directly-to-s3-with-nodejs-aws-sdk)
2. [link2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html) Using the AWS SDK in javascript.
3. Tried ways with `save()` and `saveAsBase64()` methods of the pdf-lib nodejs library.
4. Tried to save the modified file locally. Upload this file manually to AWS S3 and access through CDN. Able to view the PDF properly this way. So there is some issue with how the file is uploaded to S3.

Comment: You will need to set ContenDispostion fields while uploading the file. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022279/uploading-pdf-to-amazon-s3-and-display-in-browser

Comment: Thanks @VikramS for your suggestion. I've added the ContentDisposition metadata. Still, the PDF file is not showing proper contents. No change in the display. Still showing garbage.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with PDF file download, modification, upload operations. Actually the CDN had a caching policy due to which the initially generated garbage content files were getting served on further requests. After clearing the cache and trying again the files were properly viewable with the CDN URL.